# Dynamic Range Current Measurement

Tags: adc, switch-mode-power-supply, current-measurement

First of all, this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248097/current-sense-circuit-for-0-1ua-to-100ma-dynamic-range) or [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/258684/current-measurement-over-a-fairly-large-range).

I'm making an adjustable switching power supply (0-60VDC, 7A) with a panel  in front of it which contains a display and some buttons so that the user can adjust output voltage and current limit by "typing" manually *(i.e. there's no potentiometer and the user does not want any)*. Expected resolutions are, 0.1VDC for voltage and 1mA for current *(e.g. the user wants to type 23.4V & 1.234A)*. Of course, the same display will also be used for showing current drawn and actual output voltage.

Since there's no potentiometer for adjustments, I'm sure I need to use a microcontroller, a few ADCs for voltage/current measurements and DACs for generating reference voltages.

Without further ado, here's my question:

I'll go for high-side current measurement approach. Since the resolution is 1mA for current, I should be able to measure from 1mA to 7A but the problem is, I think I cannot measure 1mA with the same shunt resistor chosen for 7A. So, my solution is like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgns5h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*(RELAY is from SHRACK with a current carrying capacity of 8A per contact. Both shunt resistors are 3W through hole resistors with low temp coeffs.)*

My idea is to drive the relay on when the current exceeds 1A and off when the current is less than 1A. But I cannot foresee the effect(s) of relay's switch on and off action during operation.

What do you think? Do you see any problem with this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Most designs I have seen use low-side current measuring since then the commonmode level of the opamps stays the same (over output voltage), this could be crucial to you as offset might change over CMM level. Are you planning to use an ADC+uC for voltage regulation ? I'd prefer a solution where you use an "analog" loop to control the voltage but make the loop's reference voltage with an ADC.

Comment: According to my needs, high side current is better for now. For regulation, I'm not planning to use ADC+uC. Instead, traditional comparator & optocoupler aporoach is the way I go. But for generating reference voltages of comparators, I'll use uC & DACs.

Comment: As has been said, your 7000:1 dynamic range plus high-side monitoring make for a very difficult challenge. Standard diff-amp designs aren't going to cut it.  For high-side measurement you might look into the Allegro MicroSystems line of hall-effect sensors (http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs.aspx).  However, these don't provide the dynamic range you are looking for.  These can resolve perhaps 10mA with a 10A full-scale.

Answer (score 2):

With the high resolution you're hoping for, I'd recommend you rethink your high-side sensing approach. What you need to realize is that your power supply circuit ground does not have to be your output power ground. If you're careful about isolation, you can make a supply which looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faBAsH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And you need to float the supply anyways, since you cannot be certain that the customer will not someday decide to reuse the supply in a floating configuration.

As has been commented, doing high-side current sensing requires careful attention to CMRR issues, not to mention the relatively large level shifts required. With 1 mA resolution (and presumably accuracy), keeping measurements within accuracy specs, particularly at high voltages, will be quite challenging. Low-side sensing is far more forgiving.

Answer (score 2):

With high-side current sensing, dealing with *both* a 60 V offset *and* high dynamic range current measurements requires some finesse. Add a local low-voltage floating DC supply (like a battery), which is attached to the power supplies' positive terminal. This will power current sensing circuits - so that no 60 V common-mode voltage will disturb measurements.
From here, you can proceed with current measurements a few ways:

- Convert analog-to-digital and send results optically to microcontroller. The ADC type can be a (simple) voltage-to-frequency type. These are inherently monotonic, and many have good linearity.
- Chop and amplify voltage across current-sense resistor, relay optically or with a transformer to microcontroller.

A 4066 or 4053 DPDT analog switch (many others are available) is capable of switching the voltage across the small-value current sense resistor from one polarity to the other, creating a square-wave AC voltage whose amplitude is directly proportional to DC current through the current-sense resistor. This voltage can be amplified and then transferred back to the microcontroller with a small transformer. Chopping frequency can be high enough that a small ferrite transformer will do. Or an analog optical transfer device can be used.
Chopping avoids many errors introduced through DC offsets of amplifiers, and (noise floor allowing) may mean that one current-sense resistor may suffice:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwzzex.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Don't like these complex options? Then do low-side current sensing where common-mode 60 volt is reduced to millivolts.

Answer (score 0):

> I should be able to measure from 1mA to 7A

that's a range of 7000x or 12.7bits of resolution. Plus some noise, you are looking at a 16bit adc. doable with a single adc.

The key will be to keep the sampling resistors cool. HP holds a patent on covering a range of current measurement. might be useful here.